# Where is ListenActivity activity?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I want my workflow to be able to respond to an activity generated from host.
I can use Receive activity to wait for external events, but Receive only works (as far as I understand) in a context of a workflow web service.

In Workflow 1.0 (AKA 3.5) there was a Listen activity that could listen for events from host.

I understand I can do woodoo with bookmarks, but is there a replacement for old Listen Activity? or do I just **use** old activity (form System.Workflow) namespace?

Answer (score 0):

It's called Pick activity. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd807389.aspx. This might be better source http://blogs.msdn.com/b/flow/archive/2009/12/31/event-driven-execution-in-net-4-0-with-the-pick-activity.aspx

Comment: Pick implements branching. Link you linked uses Receive activity to receive an event. I did mention that Receive is not what I need.